# How to choose a zip file using JFileChooser in java

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am trying to unzip a zipped folder and put all the text files which is present inside that zipped folder in the same drive after unzipping it.This is the code.

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Unzip implements ActionListener
{
    // JFrame f;
    JFileChooser c;
    String folderName;File f;char first;

    Unzip()
    {
        c=new JFileChooser();
        c.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        c.setDialogTitle("choose file");

        int x=c.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(x==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            f=c.getSelectedFile();
            first=f.toString().charAt(0);
            folderName=f.getName();
            System.out.println(f.getName());
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

        try{
            ZipFile zfile=new ZipFile(f);

            Enumeration enm=zfile.entries();
            while(enm.hasMoreElements())
            {
                ZipEntry entry=(ZipEntry)enm.nextElement();
                String name=entry.getName();
                System.out.println("name  "+name);
                File file=new File(first+":\\"+name);
                InputStream is=zfile.getInputStream(entry);
                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
                int length=0;
                while((length=is.read())!=-1)
                {
                    fos.write(length);
                }
                is.close();
                fos.close();
            }
            zfile.close();
            }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        new Unzip();
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the zipped foler which is present in G:\ drive isn't visible when i try to navigate for that folder using JFileChooser.

What should i do so that i am able to pick that zipped folder to unzip.

Comment: I think you should show your code where you set up the JFileChooser. I don't think the code that reads your zip file has anything to do with your problem, as it only gets run once you actually _select_ a file

Comment: I have uploaded the complete code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is on this line:

```
c.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

The JFileChooser will only let you select directories, which is why your zip file doesn't show up.

Just remove this line and your code should work.